# Hello , currently learning and I am in need of some assistance. I need to write a query that will return a table with select columns

Tags: sql

Write a query that will return a table with the following columns:
User ID, Site ID, User Name, Total Sales, Total Refunds, Net Amount Collected

I need to write a query that will return a table which at the moment im trying to figure out thanks.

Tried select statement but failed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E66Ej.png)

Comment: Make it possible to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Tony, based on your image it looks like you are looking to join at the UserID. This link might help figure out what is wrong with your Select Statement. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Where is the SELECT statement that you tried? As mentioned, you probably need an INNER JOIN. Hopefully if this homework you've been given, the topic of JOIN queries may have been raised in your classes so far? Did your query try to make use of one? Without showing us what you tried or describing what actually happened when you did, there's no way for us to know.

Comment: Thanks for helping ED and giving pointers instead of just commenting negative thoughts. This is not homework and just learning for fun , that might be what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the others that simply handing this over will not help your learning much. There are a bunch of concepts that you need to learn here. Submitting this answer for your homework might be awkward (and result in a score of `0`) if you can't explain it!

[Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[Aggregate Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[Outer Joins](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-outer-joins/)

```
with cte_sales as
(
    select
    t.[User Id],
    t.[Site Id],
    sum(t.Amount) as [Total Sales]
    from Transactions t
    where t.[Transaction Type] = 'Sale'
    group by t.[User Id],
             t.[Site Id]
),
cte_refunds as
(
    select
    t.[User Id],
    t.[Site Id],
    sum(t.Amount) as [Total Refunds]
    from Transactions t
    where t.[Transaction Type] = 'Refund'
    group by t.[User Id],
             t.[Site Id]
)
select
u.[User Id],
u.[Site Id],
u.[Name] as [User Name],
coalesce(s.[Total Sales],0) as [Total Sales],
abs(coalesce(r.[Total Refunds],0)) as [Total Refunds],
(coalesce(s.[Total Sales],0) + coalesce(r.[Total Refunds],0)) as [Net Amount Collected]
from Users u
left join cte_sales s on s.[User Id] = u.[User Id]
                     and s.[Site Id] = u.[Site Id]
left join cte_refunds r on r.[User Id] = u.[User Id]
                       and r.[Site Id] = u.[Site Id]
order by u.[User Id],
         u.[Site Id];
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/82c80/5)

```
| User Id | Site Id | User Name | Total Sales | Total Refunds | Net Amount Collected |
|---------|---------|-----------|-------------|---------------|----------------------|
|       1 |       1 |    Arthur |         120 |           120 |                    0 |
|       2 |       1 |     Aaron |          90 |            30 |                   60 |
|       2 |       2 |     Brett |          90 |             0 |                   90 |
```

Comment: What was the Reddit answer and is it different to mine? Please update your question and post what you have. Or if my answer works for you, click accept.

Comment: Person used a simple aggregate function and it gave me what I needed, this pointed me in the right direction...thanks for helping me and not assuming like the others very much appreciated.